# wait for element not to have text javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that runs as soon as a element is populated I wrote a simple little piece to sort of demonstrate what I am trying to do. I want to show a run a function when the element dummy has text aka after myFunction has finished running. the whole idea is to wait for one function to run another and to use that element having data as the trigger to start the second function.

```
<body>
        <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                 document.getElementById('dummy').innerHTML = "some text";
            }
            //start this function after elemnet dummy contains "some text"
            function AlertAfterDummyHasText()
            {
                alert("dummy now has text");
            }
        </script>

        <div id='dummy'> </div>

        <input type="button" onclick="myFunction" class="btn btn-fill" value="fillTextBox" name="filleTextBox" />

</body>
```

Comment: For an opportunity at a more complete answer, please include the code for the async operation that is changing your element so we can help you hook into the completion event of that async operation as that is the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should add execution of `AlertAfterDummyHasText` inside `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction()
{
  document.getElementById('dummy').innerHTML = "some text";
  AlertAfterDummyHasText();
}

function AlertAfterDummyHasText()
{
  alert("dummy now has text");
}
```

Comment: @user3753693 - How can this possibly work if you said in a comment elsewhere that you're using an async operation that changes the text?

Comment: myFunctions is the success part of the Async so after the Async runs it kicks off AlertAfterDummyHasText()

Comment: @user3753693 - That is NOT what you show in the code in your question.  Next time, please make the code in the question match how you describe things.

Answer (score 2):

```
function elementChange(success) {
  if(success()) { alert('added text') }
}

function addText() {
  document.getElementById('mainbar').innerHTML = "Hello"; 
  elementChange(function() {
    return true;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this:

```
document.getElementById('dummy').innerHTML = "some text";
alert("dummy now has text");
```

Javascript will run run the first command, putting HTML into #dummy, then alert that it has text.

Comment: I have a async function that runs that fills a form. I  need to wait for the form fill to complete to run another function on that data

Comment: Next time post relevent code with your question pls.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit, now that you've revealed that the text is changed in an async operation.**

There are multiple options:

1. Hook into the completion callback of the async event code that changes the text of `dummy` so you can send a notification or just call your other function after the text has been changed.  If it's all your code, then this is probably the simplest way and most reliable way.
2. Create a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that watches for changes to the `dummy` element and when the right type of change occurs, you can execute your function.  The now standard mutation observers require IE11+.
3. Poll the tell in a recurring timer to see when you notice a change.  While this is attractive for its simplicity, it is generally a bad idea to use this design pattern because it's bad for battery life in a mobile device and there will be some sort of timer delay since you can't/shouldn't poll super fast.

If it's all your code, then for the first option, you can just call `myFunction()` and then immediately call some other function.  The setting of the text is synchronous (there's no delay, it happens immediately) so you don't need to wait for anything.  Once `myFunction()` has been called, the text is there.

```
myFunction();
AlertAfterDummyHasText();
```

Comment: out of 2 and 3 which one is easier to implement?

Comment: @user3753693 - 3 is easier to implement and works with older browsers, but is not recommended for the reasons I mention.  If you can do it, #1 is easy and cross browser and recommended.

Comment: @user3753693 - Now that I see in some other comment that you have an async form fill that you're trying to wait for (you should have said that in your question and showed us the code for that), then the story is different.  The ideal case is to hook into the async event and call your code when you get a completion callback for the async event.  See how I've edited my first point above.

Answer (score 1):

Listening for changes to the content of a non-user element like a `div` is possible using relatively new [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but is there a reason why you couldn't just call the function you want after setting the value?

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('dummy').innerHTML = "some text";
    AlertAfterDummyHasText();
}
```

If you're doing this in multiple places and find this tedious, you could always make a helper function to set the innerHTML and then call your function for you.

Comment: can not believe i did not think of this it works perfectly